# Java - Resetting InputStream

Tags: java, input, stream

I'm dealing with some Java code in which there's an InputStream that I read one time and then I need to read it once again in the same method.

The problem is that I need to reset it's position to the start in order to read it twice.

I've found a hack-ish solution to the problem:

```
is.mark(Integer.MAX_VALUE);

//Read the InputStream is fully
// { ... }

try
{
    is.reset();
}
catch (IOException e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Does this solution lead to some unespected behaviours? Or it will work in it's dumbness?

Comment: It might fail in situations that the reading code will `mark()` it as well.

Comment: You may be able to extend InputStream, override the mark method so that it can only be called once in an instance.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As written, you have no guarantees, because `mark()` is not required to report whether it was successful. To get a guarantee, you must first call [markSupported()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#markSupported%28%29), and it must return `true`.

Also as written, the specified read limit is very dangerous. If you happen to be using a stream that buffers in-memory, it will potentially allocate a 2GB buffer. On the other hand, if you happen to be using a `FileInputStream`, you're fine.

A better approach is to use a `BufferedInputStream` with an explicit buffer.

Comment: That means that a BufferedInputStream can be traversed twice?

Comment: @iMineLink - Yes, provided that you give it a large enough buffer. There's nothing that's going to magically store bytes without consuming memory. If that's an issue, you'll need to store the data in a local file (I'm assuming, based on other comments, that you're reading from a socket).

Comment: My fault not to have well specified it: I'm reading from an InputStream returned by a getResourceAsStream(xyz) which I think acts as a FileInputStream. So I'll try wrapping it in a BufferedInputStream with explicit buffer size.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on the InputStream implementation. You can also think whether it will be better if you use byte[]. The easiest way is to use Apache [commons-io](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/):

```
byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(inputSream);
```

Comment: The byte[] would be too heavy for me to alloc...I already tried things like that and on some Android devices i got a OOM...should I compress it? How can I in that case?

Comment: If you are using SocketInputStream, you can not use mark() to read it more than once. If you don't have enough memory to save the stream data as a byte array, you can try to redirect the InputStream data to a temporary file, and then you can read the data from that file, using BufferedInputStream ( [which supports mark()](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/io/bufferedinputstream_mark.htm) ) or RandomAccessFile.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this reliably; some `InputStream`s (such as ones connected to terminals or sockets) don't support `mark` and `reset` (see [`markSupported`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#markSupported%28%29)). If you really have to traverse the data twice, you need to read it into your own buffer.

Answer (score 2):

For me, the easiest solution was to pass the object from which the InputStream could be obtained, and just obtain it again. In my case, it was from a `ContentResolver`.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to reset the `InputStream` load it into a buffer like a `StringBuilder` or if it's a binary data stream a `ByteArrayOutputStream`. You can then process the buffer within the method as many times as you want.

```
ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

int read = 0;
byte[] buff = new byte[1024];
while ((read = inStream.read(buff)) != -1) {
    bos.write(buff, 0, read);
}
byte[] streamData = bos.toByteArray();
```

Comment: As commented at the other similar answer, the byte[] would be too heavy for me to alloc...