# FilterReader Class's mark method

Tags: java, stream

```
public void mark(int readAheadLimit)
          throws IOException
```

FilterReader class in Java.io package has a mark method that marks the next element, what is the use of that parameter in that method.
JavaDocs - **Limit on the number of characters that may be read while still preserving the mark. After reading this many characters, attempting to reset the stream may fail**

What does that mean . Examples and explanations are appreciated about failing reset and what does that parameter do!!

Comment: Here is the link to the official JavaDocs: [FilterReader.mark](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/io/FilterReader.html#mark(int))

Comment: Note that `FilterReader` is an abstract class, and the only implementation in the core library is `PushbackReader`, which does not support `mark`.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18793840/java-resetting-inputstream

Answer (score 0):

There is a better explanation in [`InputStream.mark`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/io/InputStream.html#mark(int)). A reader that supports `mark()` should mirror this behavior, e.g. by delegating it to the underlying `InputStream`:

> Marks the current position in this input stream. A subsequent call to the reset method repositions this stream at the last marked position so that subsequent reads re-read the same bytes.
>
> The readlimit arguments tells this input stream to allow that many bytes to be read before the mark position gets invalidated.
>
> The general contract of mark is that, if the method markSupported returns true, the stream somehow remembers all the bytes read after the call to mark and stands ready to supply those same bytes again if and whenever the method reset is called. However, the stream is not required to remember any data at all if more than readlimit bytes are read from the stream before reset is called.
>
> Marking a closed stream should not have any effect on the stream.
>
> The mark method of InputStream does nothing.

So, the parameter tells the `mark()` method how large the buffer for remembering elements needs to be. This allows it to allocate a buffer of appropriate size, if needed.

Comment: i still do not understand the use of that method's parameter